# why append is not working? this.append is not a function

Tags: javascript

When I drag and drop the green box into another col I get this error:

> this.append is not a function

Why?

https://jsfiddle.net/gdxwks0t/1/

```
const cols = document.getElementsByClassName('col')
const item = document.querySelector('.item')

for (const col of cols) {
  col.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  })
  col.addEventListener("drop", () => {
    alert(this)
    this.append(item)
  })
}
```

```
<div class="col">
  <div draggable="true" class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
```

Comment: If you want `this` within the call to the handler to be set by the DOM, don't use an arrow function. Arrow functions *close over* `this`, they don't get it set by how they're called like traditional functions do. See the linked question for details.

Comment: you can also use `event.target.append(item);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Arrow (`=>`) function expressions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although **without its own bindings to the `this`**, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target` keywords.

Use normal function syntax instead.

```js
const cols = document.getElementsByClassName('col')
const item = document.querySelector('.item')

for (const col of cols) {
  col.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  })
  col.addEventListener("drop", function() {
    alert(this)
    this.append(item)
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}
.item {
  background: #6dc06d;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.col {
  float: left;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: white;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div draggable="true" class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
```